# Should we narrow [narrowing] | [type-narrowing]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Should these two tags be merged?

[narrowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/narrowing): 128 questions, 22 with no upvoted or accepted answers

> A type conversion where the destination type which cannot represent all values in the source type.

[type-narrowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-narrowing): 79 questions, 18 with no upvoted or accepted answers, no usage guidance but it seems the same as the first.

Comment: Possibly need clean up first for [some of 'narrowing' questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bnarrowing%5d%20-%5btype-narrowing%5d%20-type%20-conversion%20is%3aq&searchOn=3), since some of them are mistagged, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52169931/emacs-narrow-by-regex, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624596/bing-search-api-narrow-by-date, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387287/emacs-same-buffer-two-windows-one-narrowed-one-not

Comment: Short answer: yes. Longer answer: type-narrowing is probably better after cleanup of narrowing as @AndrewT. said.